# Returning true if objects can't move in a 2d array

Tags: java

There is a lot of classes so I'm just going to simplify the question. Basically I have a 2D array of different objects:

Objects:

```
 '*' - Blockcade
 '.' - Dot
 ' ' - Empty
 'A' - Player
 'B' - Player 

***************
**** * * ******
****   **** * *
*..A*      *B**
***************
```

I defined a method `getObject(x, y)` which returns the object at the location specified by the `x` and `y` coordinates.

Player has the methods: `getX()` and `getY()` which returns the `x` and `y` coordinates of the player object.

What I'm trying to do is create a method which returns true if the surrounding tiles for both players are either an `'*'` object or an `'.'` object. So, for example, if the right, left, top and bottom tile for players is surrounded by `'*'` and `'.'` objects, then the method should return true.

```
***************
**** * * ******
****   **** * * = True
*..A*      *B**
***************

***************
**** * * ******
****   ****   *
*..A        B**  = False
***************
```

What I tried and the way I thought of doing this is as follow:

```
public Boolean cantMove() {
    return (((game.getObject(player1.getX(), player1.getY() + 1) instanceof Blockcade) || (game
            .getObject(player1.getX(), player1.getY() + 1) instanceof Dot))
            && ((game.getObject(player1.getX(), player1.getY() - 1) instanceof Blockcade) || (game
                    .getObject(player1.getX(), player1.getY() - 1) instanceof Dot))
            && ((game.getObject(player1.getX() + 1, player1.getY()) instanceof Blockcade) || (game
                    .getObject(player1.getX() + 1, player1.getY()) instanceof Dot))
            && ((game.getObject(player1.getX() - 1, player1.getY()) instanceof Blockcade) || (game
                    .getObject(player1.getX() - 1, player1.getY()) instanceof Dot))
            && ((game.getObject(player2.getX(), player2.getY() + 1) instanceof Blockcade) || (game
                    .getObject(player2.getX(), player2.getY() + 1) instanceof Dot))
            && ((game.getObject(player2.getX(), player2.getY() - 1) instanceof Blockcade) || (game
                    .getObject(player2.getX(), player2.getY() - 1) instanceof Dot))
            && ((game.getObject(player2.getX() + 1, player2.getY()) instanceof Blockcade) || (game
                    .getObject(player2.getX() + 1, player2.getY()) instanceof Dot)) && ((game
            .getObject(player2.getX() - 1, player2.getY()) instanceof Blockcade) || (game
            .getObject(player2.getX() - 1, player2.getY()) instanceof Dot)));
}
```

This seems quite messy and I feel as if there is a better way to do this and make the code even better. I am not too sure if there is any way other than this so I am hoping someone can help me with this. With what I have now, if I were to add another player, for example 'C', then the code becomes much larger and it seems like its a reuse of code. I was wondering if anyone knows a better way to handle this situation or know a way to simplify this method. Thank you for those who help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a `Player` array and run `cantMove()` on each player individually to check whether they are surrounded based on their current coordinates (Using `getX()` and `getY()`). Right now you're manually calling your methods on each and every player, which could be compressed into one general case.

```
    Player[] players;

    //Players added to array here

    public boolean someMethod() {
        for (Player p : players)
            if (!p.cantMove())
                return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Also:

Assuming you have your world represented in some kind of array, since you can retrieve an object using coordinates, you could try checking instead whether the object at a certain location is null, instead of checking what it could be.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could try checking to see if a single space exists instead of checking to see if a space doesn't exist if that makes sense.